# Iframe in webview post to different domain on Samsung device

Tags: android, cordova, iframe, android-webview, ionic-framework

Our Ionic app is loading an Iframe at an external URL for credit card payment purpose. The form is loaded and the user is shown a credit card form. When the user presses the pay button they might be redirected to a different page to enter their 3D secure password. This redirection doesn't work on any Samsung-device we've tested, but it works on other devices.

Looking in `chrome://inspect` (inspecting a Samsung device) shows me that the credit card form has posted data to a new domain, and the page loading has status "pending". So the page never loads.

I guess there is some security settings on Samsung devices preventing posts from one domain to another in a signed application, but how do we make it work?

Comment: At least take a look at CORS, this should be the issue. Maybe you need to allow this in the `config.xml` in the `<access origin="">` tags. Also consider using the InAppBrowser plugin instead of an iframe.

Comment: Unfortunately I wont be able to use the InAppBrowser, but I can change `config.xml`. The config contains the tag `<access origin="*">` which I think should work (but it doesn't). How do I proceed?

Comment: Question updated with some more info (realised there's only problem on Samsung devices)